# how to find out which of the resources are linked to a storage account?

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-graph

I need a way of finding out which one of the Azure resources are linked to a storage account and which one of the storage accounts is it.
There are A LOT of resources, about 2000.

I really don't know how to go about this.
Can't use PowerShell or Cloud Shell because of user restrictions.

Comment: Did you try with Azure storage explorer? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/storage/storage-explorer/

Comment: yes, i tried but couldn't find out how

Comment: Is Azure resource graph queries works for you? @anadamasceno13

Comment: I don't know how to use resource graph. I don't know how to get to the query

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to implement it PowerShell or CLI, you can use Azure storage explorer or Azure resource graph queries.

*Check below:*

1. *Azure storage explorer:*

[Download](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/storage/storage-explorer/) it into your local environment with the help of the given link and then sign into your Azure account. Now you will be able to view all the storage account information specifically as shown.

[image]

2. *Azure resource graph:*

Use below query in resource graph explorer to view the required data.

```bash
resources
| where type == "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
| project StorageAccountName = name, ResourceId = id
| join kind=inner (ResourceContainers | project ResourceId, ResourceName, ResourceType) 
on $left.ResourceId == $right.ResourceId
| project StorageAccountName, ResourceGroup
```

3. You can also check service `endpoints` under `settings` of each storage account to know the linked specific blob/file/queue services as shown.

[image]